# VBA is not updating automatically after input

Tags: vba, excel

I have created a Excel workbook for my work where I collect information. In this workbook I have a sheet where details in various currencies can be filled in. Based on the selection by the preparer the value in cell B5 will change to either USD or LC. In case the value in cell B5 will be USD, columns C and E should be hidden. The issue in here is that this code will not immediately unhide the columns. After clicking on a random cell, the columns are hidden. Please let me know if there is a solution for this issue whereby the columns are hidden without clicking on a random cell each time. Thank you.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Range("B5").Value = "USD" Then
        Union(Columns("C"), Columns("E")).EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    ElseIf Range("B5").Value = "LC" Then
        Union(Columns("C"), Columns("E")).EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    End If
End Sub
```

Thank you all for your comments. Let me further elaborate on my issue. In principle my VBA code works. The only thing is that after cell B5 is changed to USD, initially nothing happens. After I click on a random cell in this sheet, the VBA code works and hide the columns. The same is applicable in case the value in cell B5 is LC. Then again the VBA code does not work immediately. After clicking on a random cell in the sheet the columns are unhided.

A small update with respect to cell B5. So cell B5 contains a formula that is linked to listed cell in another sheet. After a value is selected from the list in another sheet, cell B5 will determine through the IF functions if the value in B5 will be LC or USD.

I am now afraid that after the preparer select in the listed cell a value, it will not click on a random cell in designated sheet resulting that he or she will see the wrong information.

Please let me know if you require further information. Thank you.

PS. I am not very strong in creating VBA codes.

Comment: Suggestion: Make an easier IF. Just if B5=USD then hide, if not, unhide. There is no need to specify B5="LC". If B5=USD then Hide Else Unhide.

Comment: @QHarr Yes, sorry, i typed fast and did not the proper format. Let me fix it

Comment: What does doesn't immediately unhide mean? At present it will hide if B5 is "USD" and unhide if "LC". Seems to run perfectly well for me.

Comment: @QHarr Ok, comments can be edited only in the first 5 minutes and i can't fix it :O Sorry about that.

Comment: Dear all, I have tried all the solutions as mentioned, but unfortunately, my issue is still not solved. I have included some further explanations that may help. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You're using the wrong event.

`SelectionChange` fires when you select a different cell, etc.

`Change` fires immediately after a cell's contents change.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Range("B5").Value = "USD" Then
        Union(Columns("C"), Columns("E")).EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    ElseIf Range("B5").Value = "LC" Then
        Union(Columns("C"), Columns("E")).EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    End If
End Sub
```

---

### Alternate Solution:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target = Range("B5") Then Union(Columns("C"), Columns("E")).EntireColumn.Hidden = (Target.Value = "USD")
End Sub
```

<sub>(adapted from @Vityata's [comment below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49649161/vba-is-not-updating-automatically-after-input#comment86306532_49649264))</sub>

---

### More Information:

- MSDN : [**`Worksheet.SelectionChange` Event** (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheet-selectionchange-event-excel)
- MSDN : [**`Worksheet.Change` Event** (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheet-change-event-excel)

Comment: Or you can even go with one liner like this: `Union(Columns("C"), Columns("E")).EntireColumn.Hidden = cbool(Range("B5").Value = "USD")`

Comment: On a side note, although the event is not the good one, the code is working correctly on my side. It's just fired more times than necessary, but it's not because of the event chosen that the OP has the issue - I guess it's more about ScreenUpdating issues.

Comment: @Vityata - smart!  You won't be offended if I added that to the answer for the OP?

Comment: and in case if the sheets are dynamically added, then you could go with something like **Workbook_SheetSelectionChange** and this will then start working for all worksheets. This sub needs to be put inside the ThisWorkbook Module. Also, you can write an if loop inside this sub to control which sheet needs to be considered and which one doesn't need to be considered.

Comment: @ashleedawg - nope, it's perfect :)

Answer (score 0):

A few changes to your code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = "$B$5" Then
        If Range("B5").Value = "USD" Then
            Union(Columns("C"), Columns("E")).EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        Else
            Union(Columns("C"), Columns("E")).EntireColumn.Hidden = False
        End If
        Application.Calculate
    End If
End Sub
```

1: the right event is `Change` (when a value changes in the sheet), not `SelectionChange` (when the selection changes).

2: Your code works on my side, so I guess it's not working on your side because you have some calculation off. I've added the line `Application.Calculate` which will refresh the spreadsheet even if your calculations are set to manual.

3: I've added an `If Target.Address` condition to check only when the cell that changed is the right one.

4: I've added just `Else` instead of `ElseIf cell = "LC"`, because it's faster and because I think it's cleaner (if the user removes completely the value of the currency and before it was USD, nobody will unhide the columns C and E).

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. I have tried this VBA code, but unfortunately it is not working. I have included some further explanation in my initial question. Thank you.

Comment: One is assuming that Range("B5") is changed physically. That would be the only way Worksheet_change event would kick in.

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple,

```
    Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Range("B5")
    If rng.Value = "USD" Then Columns("C:E").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    If rng.Value = "LC" Then Columns("C:E").EntireColumn.Hidden = False

    End Sub
```